# Computing size of permutation group from generators

Tags: ds.algorithms, permutations

You're given $k$ permutations $a_1,\dots,a_k$. Consider closure of this set under the composition operation. What are most efficient and simple algorithms to calculate the size of this closure?

Comment: Don't think there are efficient algorithms for doing this in a classical setting

Comment: I doubt that since there at least one such algorithm in [Polynomial-time algorithms for permutation groups](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4567802/?reload=true). What is asked here is maybe some general overview of existing algorithms and their key ideas.

Comment: If you already know of some algorithms for this problem, please edit your question to provide a summary of the algorithms/references you already know of.  As our [help/on-topic] says, "Try to make your question interesting for others by providing some background knowledge. Remember, questions should be based on knowledge sharing".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient (and also simplest) algorithms for this are based on the notion of a [strong generating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_generating_set), introduced by Sims. Strong generating sets can be computed efficiently using the [Schreier-Sims algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm). Essentially any introductory book that talks about computational group theory should have a decent introduction to this (and if it contains an introduction to this that isn't decent, I'd think it's not a very good book). While the standard deterministic algorithm for this takes quadratic time, there is a randomized nearly-linear time algorithm. See Seress's book "Permutation Group Algorithms," Chapter 4 (the nearly-linear time Monte Carlo algorithm is Theorem 4.5.5).